# Is this possible to make video gallery in android like image gallery

Tags: java, android

How to make video gallery like image gallery .We are giving lots of drawable in image gallery,like this can we give lots of url for video gallery. For ex this is the image gallery Relavant Link 
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/image-gallery-example-in-android/ 
like this slide sharing of video gallery how we can make..

Comment: should we give you the whole code?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu do you have some example or source code like that,it will be very useful for my learning

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu dude if you have any example link can you post here

Comment: sry i cant mail you dew to some reason.... :(

Comment: @KarthickM accept the answer if this is what you want or comment ....

Comment: @KarthickM accept the answer if this is what you want or comment

Answer (score 7):

> my main gallay class

```
  public class HorizontalScrollExampleActivity extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener {
    LinearLayout myGallery;
    Cursor cursor;
    private ArrayList<VideoViewInfo> _videoRows;
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallaryview);

        myGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        loaddata();
        /*
         * File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
         * 
         * File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles(); for (File file : files) {
         * myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath())); }
         */
    }

    private void loaddata() {
        String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID };

        String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE };

        cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                mediaColumns, null, null, null);

        ArrayList<VideoViewInfo> videoRows = new ArrayList<VideoViewInfo>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                VideoViewInfo newVVI = new VideoViewInfo();
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
                Cursor thumbCursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID
                                + "=" + id, null, null);
                if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));
                    Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
                }

                newVVI.filePath = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
                newVVI.title = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
                Log.v("", newVVI.title);
                newVVI.mimeType = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE));
                Log.v("", newVVI.mimeType);
                videoRows.add(newVVI);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        _videoRows = videoRows;
        myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(videoRows));
    }

    View insertPhoto(ArrayList<VideoViewInfo> videoRows) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 250));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        for (int i = 0; i < videoRows.size(); i++) {

            Bitmap bmThumbnail;

            bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                    videoRows.get(i).filePath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(220, 220));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            // imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.canada);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
            imageView.setPadding(20, 40, 20, 40);
            imageView.setTag(videoRows.get(i).filePath);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
            layout.addView(imageView);

        }

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mVideoView.isPlaying() == true) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getTag().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String filepath = v.getTag().toString();
        play(filepath);

    }

    public void play(String index) {

        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(index);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

        mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {
        Bitmap bm = null;

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return bm;
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

> xml for the galary class

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mygallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

> class VideoViewInfo

```
class VideoViewInfo {
    String filePath;
    String mimeType;
    String thumbPath;
    String title;
}
```

> Note : code need some little modification as per the logic . but it will do what you are looking for.... i will update it soon.... till then cheers..... 
>   Update: code updated working fine.